# Prove if $\sqrt r$ is rational, then $r$ is also rational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers

> How would I prove that if $\sqrt r$ is rational, then $r$ is also rational?

I started assuming that $\sqrt r$ is rational then $\sqrt r=\frac{p}{q}$ where $\gcd(p,q) = 1$. Then $r$ would be $p^2/q^2$ but ... how can I prove that is rational?.

Comment: You've written $r$ as a ratio of coprime integers, so what's the problem?

Comment: The **proof-theory** tag should not be used for questions such as these.

Comment: **Hint:** Recall the definition of rational number. **Remark:** You don't need the $\text{gdc}$ part here.

Comment: Can you prove that if $k$ is rational then $k^2$ is also rational?

Comment: @JMoravitz I think that is my problem

Comment: @user11235813 I apologize, I will remove it now

Comment: You are overcomplicating this. I recommend trying to prove a stronger result: that if $a, b$ are rational, then $a\times b$ is also rational.

HINT: use the fact that $m\times n$ is an integer whenever $m, n$ are integers.

Comment: @carmichael561 I understand know, when you say coprime integers I could figure that my solution is true, thanks.

Comment: @NoahSchweber that works too, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution:

Suppose $\sqrt{r}$ is rational. By definition, then, can find some $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\sqrt{r} = \frac{p}{q} $. This means that

$$ r = \frac{ p^2}{q^2} = \frac{ p \cdot p}{q \cdot q} \in \mathbb{Q} $$

and thus the result follows.

Comment: Strictly speaking you should note that since a field has no zero divisors, we have $q^2 \not = 0$. (Edit: Ah, actually your conclusion follows from the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ under multiplication. Sorry.)